# In Angular How to send one component to another data without parent child relationship, without queryString in url

Tags: angular, angular6

Don't have parent child relationship,
Don't have query String in URL
Don't use any services

Answer (score 0):

Use get and set method to send data one component and another
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html